# Python: "TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python-2.7

I attempted to research this issue prior to making an account and posting. My research was inconclusive largely because I am new to Python.

***Problem:*** I am trying to match a if statement to ensure that a server is up and running prior to running my main code.

***Solution sets that didn't work:***
1) I tried the below ***if statement***
2) I tried piping the variable to look for leading/ending spaces.
3) I tried a ***response.split***
4) I tried a ***response[:3]*** to match the first 3 characters and got the above error

***What the script will do:*** The elastisearch server returns "< Response [200] >" if it is up and running.

*Code:*

```
Import requests    
es_server = "IP:PORT"
response = requests.get("http://" + es_server)
if response == '<Response [200]>':
 print "yep"
```

I get unicode errors if I try response.text()

Comment: above worked, thanks for the quick response and explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `requests.get` is not a string but a `Response` object holding all sorts of information. `<Response [200]>` is just the *string representation* of that object, but it is not equal to the object itself. See [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for some documentation.

If you want to test the status code of the response, you should check like this:

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    print "yep"
```